# Can I use fstream in C++ to read or write file when I'm implementing a disk management component of DBMS

Tags: c++, database, fstream

In C++, I know I can use read or write file using system function like read or write and I can also do that with fstream's help.

Now I'm implementing a disk management which is a component of DBMS. For simplicity I only use disk management to manage the space of a Unix file.

All I know is fstream wrap system function like read or write and provide some buffer.
However I was wondering whether this will affect atomicity and synchronization or not?

My question is which way should I use and why?

Comment: yeah...I take a overlook about this page. Maybe I'm wrong but I can't find something useful or relative. It says little about <fstream> and camparison between fstream and system function

Answer (score 0):

No. Particularly not with Unix. A DBM is going to want contiguous files. That means either a unix variant that support them or creating a disk partition.

You're also going to want to handle the buffering; not following the C++ library's buffering.

I could go on but streams are for - - streams of data -- not secure, reliable structured data.

Answer (score 0):

The following information about synchronization and thread safety of 'fstream' can be found from ISO C++ standard.

**27.2.3 Thread safety [iostreams.threadsafety]**

> Concurrent access to a stream object (27.8, 27.9), stream buffer
>   object (27.6), or C Library stream (27.9.2) by multiple threads may
>   result in a data race (1.10) unless otherwise specified (27.4). [
>   Note: Data races result in undefined behavior (1.10). —end note ]
>
> If one thread makes a library call a that writes a value to a stream
>   and, as a result, another thread reads this value from the stream
>   through a library call b such that this does not result in a data
>   race, then a’s write synchronizes with b’s read.

C/C++ file I/O operation are not thread safe by default. So if you are planning to use fstream of open/write/read system call, then you would have to use synchronization mechanism by yourself in your implementation. You may use 'std::mutex' mechanism provided in new C++ standard(.i.e C++11) to synchronize your file I/O.